# About using ```hcitool``` to get bluetooth rssi

Tags: bluetooth, rssi

I use `sudo hcitool rssi AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` to test 2 phones, but the results are 0. I also try to use python program (https://github.com/ewenchou/bluetooth-proximity), the result is also 0. I don't know where went wrong. Besides, I use `bluetoothctl-scan on` and can get their mac address and rssi although the value is not accuracy.
Please, give me some advice.

Comment: hciattach, hciconfig, hcitool, hcidump, rfcomm, sdptool, ciptool, and gatttool were [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) by the BlueZ project in 2017. If you are following a tutorial that uses them, there is a chance that it might be out of date. There is this answer about scanning for RSSI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64069771/7721752 .

Comment: Really thank you for your advice, but I cannot find the phone although I can find many mace address and rssi of other unknow devices.

Comment: Is your phone advertising/discoverable?

Comment: Thank you, I found them. By the way, do you know if I just want to find one device instead of all devices, what should I do?

Comment: Set the `SetDiscoveryFilter` https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt